# Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate

Tags: spring-boot, javabeans

I am new to spring boot I tried this example
[Spring boot oauth2](https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-oauth2/)

it gives me this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
        at com.demo27.Demo27Application.main(Demo27Application.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer.geDefaultMessageConverters(DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer.java:121) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer.<init>(DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer.java:57) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.AbstractOAuth2SecurityExceptionHandler.<init>(AbstractOAuth2SecurityExceptionHandler.java:46) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler.<init>(OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler.java:36) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.<init>(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.java:67) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration.configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration.java:78) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:238) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:336) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:113) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cbf5e003.init(<generated>) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:338) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:300) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:125) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
        ... 41 common frames omitted
```

My code

```java
package com.demo27.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;


@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${user.oauth.user.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${user.oauth.user.password}")
    private String password;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize**", "/login**", "/error**")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(username).password(passwordEncoder().encode(password)).roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

and

```
package com.demo27.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;


@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Value("${user.oauth.clientId}")
    private String clientID;

    @Value("${user.oauth.clientSecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${user.oauth.redirectUris}")
    private String redirectURLs;

    @Value("${user.oauth.accessTokenValidity}")
    private int accessTokenValidity;

    @Value("${user.oauth.refreshTokenValidity}")
    private int refreshTokenValidity;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient(clientID)
            .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(clientSecret))
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
            .scopes("user_info")
            .authorities("READ_ONLY_CLIENT")
            .redirectUris(redirectURLs)
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValidity)
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(refreshTokenValidity);
    }
}
```

can anybody help me with this issue?

I tried to build spring boot oauth2 application but get this error

Comment: The error is pretty clear... -> `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException`. You don't have any XML jars added to your dependencies and thus it doesn't work (those libs got removed in JDK11 so need to be explicitly added).